# Android - Image entrance animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to create an effect similar to Facebook Home Lock screen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=HiqbNxRurFA#t=20s). Images with Burns effect.
Images(wider than the screen) start with it's left part shown and scroll smoothly to right.

I've tried to `View.animate.x(-50.0f)` but the image appears cropped when it moves. (I used `scaleType=center` and the image is larger than the screen)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I've updated the question. With what I've tried.